# TypeError during iterations within while loop

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I am having some troubles with an assigned task. I have tried to figure it out where the error is, but still with no success. I have the following (small, just for example) dataset:

```
T1              T2                     V1       V2
name_1  ['name_3', 'name_4']          [1,2]   ['a','b']
name_2  []                            []      []
name_3  ['name_1']                    [1]     ['c']
name_4  ['name_1','name_x','name_13'] [12,2,4] ['c','NA','d']
name_4  ['name_1','name_x','name_13'] [12,2,4] ['c','NA','d']
```

Since T2, V1 and V2 are shown as lists, I had to use explode() and create two new variables, new_t2 and new_t1, to check what values from those columns are still missing and need to be checked.

```
df = df.explode('T2')
```

getting the following error (caused within a function that I am going to discuss later in this post):

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution from what I understood -

1st you can flatten the dataframe to make easy calculations this can be done via(use ast.literal_eval only when explode doesn't work directly)

```
from ast import literal_eval
for col in df.columns.values[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(literal_eval) #convert to list type
df = df.set_index(['T1']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

The operation will flatten the dataframe like this -

| T1 | T2 | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_1 | name_3 | 1 | a |
| name_1 | name_4 | 2 | b |
| name_2 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| name_3 | name_1 | 1 | c |
| name_4 | name_1 | 12 | c |
| name_4 | name_x | 2 | NA |
| name_4 | name_13 | 4 | d |
| name_4 | name_1 | 12 | c |
| name_4 | name_x | 2 | NA |
| name_4 | name_13 | 4 | d |

Now, if you want tuples for only those rows in 'T2' which are not there in 'T1'. You can use apply or something else. I used apply-

```
unique_t1 = set(df['T1'].to_list())
def tuple_creation(x):
    if x['T2'] not in unique_t1:
        return (x['T2'],x['V1'],x['V2']) #if you want to add T1 in the tuple just add it here.
df['tuple'] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple_creation(x), axis=1)
```

Output (for display I've transformed tuple to '-' separated string)-

| T1 | T2 | V1 | V2 | tuple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_1 | name_3 | 1 | a |  |
| name_1 | name_4 | 2 | b |  |
| name_2 |  |  |  | nan-nan-nan |
| name_3 | name_1 | 1 | c |  |
| name_4 | name_1 | 12 | c |  |
| name_4 | name_x | 2 | NA | name_x-2-NA |
| name_4 | name_13 | 4 | d | name_13-4-d |
| name_4 | name_1 | 12 | c |  |
| name_4 | name_x | 2 | NA | name_x-2-NA |
| name_4 | name_13 | 4 | d | name_13-4-d |